# Issue in IE with downloading uncommon file extensions

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a web app running on a server within our Org. The web app allows our users to download files, specifically .pkg files

(UNIX System V .pkg files are cpio archives that contain specific file tree structures)

Anyway in Chrome and other modern browsers the file is downloaded no problem. In IE these files are opened, which presents the user with 'gibberish'. What are  possible solutions if any, to have have IE simply download the file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add a .htaccess file with the code below to my /tmp directory (this is where the files are generated for the user to download):

```
<Files ~ "\.*$">
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

You can adjust the code inside of the "" to apply to specific file types as well as files inside of folders.